# Why did West Francia fall apart?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

In my first game with the Charlemagne DLC (starting 769) King Charles Karling the Great created a pretty big realm. But then suddenly, in 791, many of his vassals, including the duchies of Brunswick, Saxony, Thüringia, Franconia and Burgundy, became independent:

[image]

I didn't see any independence revolt and I'm also not aware of any other mechanic that could have caused this.

So, what happened? Is this something specific to Charlemagne, the character? Is there something I could do to investigate this further?

Comment: Was there any event, dialogue box, or notification to accompany this?

Comment: @Studoku I wasn't playing as Charles, but I didn't see any notification.

Comment: It could have been an independence faction where Charles gave in to the demands rather than fight.

Comment: IIRC, if you're over the vassal limit then when you pass on parts of the realm will go independent of their own accord. I've seen this happen a lot in Observe games but I can't confirm it myself right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was almost certainly an independence faction.

When an independence faction reaches a sufficient size, it will present an ultimatum to its ruler. The ruler has a choice- give in to those demands, or refuse and almost certainly end up at war with that entire faction (with the faction members becoming independent if they win).

A large independence faction could potentially have a large enough army (especially if Charles's own army was depleted) that it could outnumber Charles enough that he chose not to fight. In this case, you aren't informed.